# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, typeerror, init

I am currently using Django and python to create a web app to take meter readings for my company.

I am receiving this error (Title) and I don't know what is causing it. I have

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Operational URLS
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("",include("accounts.urls")),
    path('home/' , views.home, name='home'),


    #Complexes
    #AVONLEA
    path('avn', views.AvonleaView, name='Avonlea'),
    path('cavn', views.currentavonleas, name='currentAvonleas'),
    path('Avonleacsv', views.Avonleacsv, name='Avonleacsv'),
    path('meter_readings/avonlea/<int:avonleas_pk>', views.viewavonlea, name='viewavonlea' ),
    path('meter_readings/avonlea/<int:avonleas_pk>/delete', views.deleteavonlea, name='deleteavonlea' ),
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import AvonleaForm
from .models import AvonleaClass
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View


#Operational

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'meter_readings/home.html' )


# Complexes

#AVONLEA
#
#
#

class AvonleaView( View):

    def get(self,request):
        created_nums= AvonleaClass.objects.all().values('unitNumber')

        Aprev = AvonleaClass.objects.all().order_by('-unitDateEntered')
        previousReading = Aprev[1].newReading
        # created_nums= AvonleaClass.objects.all()
        print(created_nums , previousReading)

        created_nums =[int(i['unitNumber']) for i in created_nums]
        print(created_nums , previousReading)

        form = AvonleaForm()
        return render(request,"meter_readings/avonlea.html",{'form':form , 'created_nums':created_nums , 'name':name, 'previousReading' : previousReading })

    def post(self,request):
        created_nums= AvonleaClass.objects.all().values_list('unitNumber')
        print(created_nums)
        form = AvonleaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('unt-url' , name )
            messages.success(request , 'creates successfully ')
        else:
            return render(request, 'meter_readings/avonlea.html', {'form': form ,  created_nums:created_nums })

def currentavonleas(request):
    avonleas = AvonleaClass.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'meter_readings/currentavonleas.html', {'avonleas':avonleas})

def viewavonlea(request,  avonleas_pk):
    avonlea = get_object_or_404(AvonleaClass, pk=avonleas_pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AvonleaForm(instance=avonlea)
        return render(request, 'meter_readings/viewavonleas.html', {'avonlea': avonlea, 'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form =  AvonleaForm(request.POST, instance=avonlea)
            form.save()
            return redirect('Avonlea')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'meter_readings/viewavonleas.html', {'avonlea': avonlea, 'form':form, 'error':'Bad info'})

def deleteavonlea(request, avonleas_pk):
    avonlea = get_object_or_404(AvonleaClass, pk=avonleas_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        avonlea.delete()
        return redirect('Avonlea')

import csv
def Avonleacsv(request):
    data =AvonleaClass.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="saved_file.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Unit', 'Number of Units'
                     ])
    for avonleaclass in data:
        writer.writerow([
                        avonleaclass.unitNumber,
                        avonleaclass.newReading,
                         ])
    return response
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.urls import reverse

AvonleaUnits = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,73)]

class AvonleaClass(models.Model):
    unitNumber      = models.CharField(max_length=2 ,  default='1')
    newReading = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
    difference = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    unitNotes       = models.TextField(blank=True)
    unitDateEntered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    unitProblem     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image           = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Unit ' + self.unitNumber)

Forms.py 

    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import AvonleaClass
    from django import forms
    
    AvnUnits = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,73)]
    
    class AvonleaForm(ModelForm):
        unitNumber = forms.ChoiceField(choices= AvnUnits)
        class Meta:
            model = AvonleaClass
            fields = ['unitNumber','newReading','difference', 'unitNotes','unitProblem' ,  'image']
            widgets = {
                        'unitNotes': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10}),
                        'unitReading': forms.IntegerField(),
                        'diffrence': forms.IntegerField(),
            }
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import AvonleaClass

class AvonleaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('unitDateEntered',)

admin.site.register(AvonleaClass, AvonleaAdmin)

class Birchleigh_ViewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('unitDateEntered',)
```

Avonlea.html

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% extends 'meter_readings/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<h1>{{name}} Meter Readings</h1>
{% for unit_number in form.unitNumber %}
<h6>{{ error }}</h6>


<form class="form-group mt-4" method="post"  {% if unit_number.data.value in created_nums %}  style="background-color: rgb(231, 224, 224);  " {% endif %} >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-3">
<div class="col">
  {{ unit_number.data.value}}
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="unitNumber" value="{{unit_number.data.value}}">

<div class="col" id="prev{{unit_number.data.value}}" >

  {{ previousReading }}
</div>
<div class="col"   id="readings{{unit_number.data.value}}">

  {{ form.newReading }}
</div>
<div class="col" id="difference{{unit_number.data.value}}">

  {{ form.difference }}
</div>
<div class="col">

  {{ form.unitNotes }}
</div>
<div class="col">

  {{ form.unitProblem }}
</div>
<div class="col" id="img{{unit_number.data.value}}">
  {{ form.image }}
</div>
<div class="col">
<button class="btn btn-success " type="submit"   {% if unit_number.data.value in created_nums %}  disabled {% endif %} > Save</button>




</div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
document.getElementById("img{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.disabled = true
document.getElementById("difference{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.disabled = true

  var  last = document.getElementById('readings{{unit_number.data.value}}');
  last.addEventListener('input' , (e)=>{

    last = e.target.value
   var first = document.getElementById('prev{{unit_number.data.value}}').firstElementChild.value;


 var  diff= document.getElementById('difference{{unit_number.data.value}}').firstElementChild.value= parseInt(last) - parseInt(first);

 if (diff <= 0){
   console.log(diff)
   console.log("-ve")

   document.getElementById("difference{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.style.border="2px solid red";
   document.getElementById("img{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.disabled=false

 }
 else{

  document.getElementById("difference{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.style.border="2px solid ";
  document.getElementById("img{{unit_number.data.value}}").firstElementChild.disabled=true

   console.log("+ve")
 }




  })



</script>


</form>

  {% endfor %}

<style>
  .error {
    border:2px solid red;
  }
</style>

<form method="POST", action="{% url 'currentAvonleas' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">View all Avonlea readings</button>
</form>

<form method="POST", action="{% url 'Avonleacsv' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">Export readings to Excel</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

<br>
<br>
<br>
```

home.html:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% extends 'meter_readings/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class="display-5 text-center" align-items-center>Meter Reading Application</h1>

<h3>Individual Unit Readings</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">


  <a href="{% url 'Avonlea' %}" class="btn btn-info" >Avonlea </a>

<br>
<br>

 </div>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

The exact error that is given :

> TypeError at /avn
> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/avn Django Version:   3.2
> Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:
> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Exception Location:   C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py,
> line 181, in _get_response Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.9.4 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\KylePOG\Desktop\meter-reading',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:  Sun, 30 May 2021 19:14:46 +0000 Traceback Switch to
> copy-and-paste view
> C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py,
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request) … ▶ Local vars C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py,
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) … ▶ Local vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with [**`.as_view(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) to turn a class-based view into a function that can handle the request, so:

```
path('avn', views.AvonleaView.as_view(), name='Avonlea'),
```